# com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException while running Jmeter from Jenkins shell

Tags: jmeter

While running Jmeter jmx script from Jenkins command line I am getting the below error.

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    Problem loading XML from:'/Users/msn/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/testMsn.jmx',
    conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
    org/apache/commons/lang3/CharUtils : org/apache/commons/lang3/CharUtils
```

I have all the plug-in installed in my Jmeter/lib/ext.

Can someone help me point out which jar is missing to resolve this issue

```
 Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Jmeter-First/workspace
   [workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson6757313439371769855.sh
   + /Users/msn/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t /Users/msn/apache-jmeter-  2.13/bin/TestPlan.jmx
   Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML   from:'/Users/msn/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/TestPlan.jmx', conversion error    com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:   org/apache/commons/lang3/CharUtils : org/apache/commons/lang3/CharUtils
   ---- Debugging information ----
   message             : org/apache/commons/lang3/CharUtils
   cause-exception     : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
   cause-message       : org/apache/commons/lang3/CharUtils
   first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration.  <clinit>(SampleSaveConfiguration.java:323)
   class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
   required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector
   converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
   path                :   /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector
   line number         : 46
   version             : 2.13 r1665067
   ------------------------------
 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

**lang3.CharUtils** is part of Apache Commons Lang library (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3). So make sure it is available on your classpath (for example *commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar*).

Also, make sure you are not confusing it with Commons Lang library (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang) which is a predecessor of aforementioned Apache Commons Lang. For example *commons-lang-2.4.jar*.

Comment: I have checked my maven dependencies and commons-lang3 dependency is present(3.4) and still I am getting the error

Comment: And what scope is it? Compile, provided, .. Please try to provide more detail. Thanks.

Comment: I am making a jar using from Eclipse IDE and then converting to jmx from Jmeter from the GUI and running it in Jenkins shell to invoke the jmx test case.

Comment: The above mentioned error did not come after I reinstalled Jmeter including plugins. I ensured that jar files mentioned in maven for my junit tests match in jmeter lib directory. But I ran into another issue, which I will raise in a different thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After having the same issue and not being able to resolve it by the commonly suggested solution (installing `plugins-manager.jar`), I was able to fix the issue by reinstalling JMeter on my machine.